# Matlab: replace specific argument that appears more than once

Tags: matlab

let's say I have s=g(1,2,0)+g(1,3,0)+u(1,3)+g(1,1,0) where g, u are functions; I want to replace all 3rd arguments of g to something I choose without going through my script and doing it manually.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = ... % assign some value beforehand
s = g(1,2,x) + g(1,3,x) + u(1,3) + g(1,1,x)
```

Comment: That's not what I'm asking: the existing value of the 3rd argument for every appearance of g is 0 (or say, it's anything else). Starting from this point, I want to make every appearance of g's 3rd argument a different specified value (say, 1 instead of 0).

Comment: @user2827076 in that case I think your question is unclear. Please include more information and examples in your question text.

Comment: Because I have already written a script where every occurence of g(.,.,.) has the incorrect entry in the 3rd argument, I would now like to somehow replace, with one fell swoop, specifically every 3rd argument of g(.,.,.) that appears in the script. In my example, they're 0's right now; I'd like to replace them all to be 1, for instance.

Comment: @user2827076 the error was made when writing the code. Any constant should only appear once. There is no good practice in maintaining such code except refactoring it manually and replacing the third parameter with a constant.

Answer (score 1):

What follows is an ugly hack and I don't recommend using it:

```
g = @(a,b,c) g(a,b,0)
```

This *redefines* `g` function in a way that executing after that:

```
s = g(1,2,5) + g(1,3,3) + u(1,3) + g(1,1,2)
```

actually executes:

```
s = g(1,2,0) + g(1,3,0) + u(1,3) + g(1,1,0)
```